# Qual o significado de "string"?

Tags: string, terminologia

*String* no inglês significa *linha*.

- O que isso tem a ver com as strings da programação?
- Por que elas se chamam assim?

Comment: A pensar: "linha" é a **única** tradução de *string*? Em todos os contextos ou apenas em alguns bem específicos?

Comment: O [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/string_1#string_1__5) pode ajudar nessa...

Comment: Se chama string porque antigamente cada letra era uma placa que era pintada e utilizada na impressora. Entre uma impressão e outra essas placas precisavam secar e para isso as deixavam penduradas em cordas (strings). Quando ia fazer uma nova impressão, o operador da impressora ordenava seu auxiliar a buscar uma determinada corda "traga-me a corda X" e a expressão "bring me the string X" acabou se popularizando, entendendo string como um conjunto de letras

Comment: Porque você não colocou isso como uma resposta?

Comment: @NinjaTroll porque isso não explica o que você perguntou é só uma curiosidade interessante. Se ele respondesse você aceitaria como resposta correta?

Comment: E pode, ou não, ser verdade. Sem fontes confiáveis jamais saberemos.

Comment: Acho que o comentário do @Woss respondeu de forma mais clara a segunda pergunta, embora eu não diria "um conjunto de letras", mas sim "um conjunto de caracteres", porque uma string pode conter números, espaços ou outro caractere, que não são letras.

Comment: Concordo, acho que o @Maniero deveria editar a pergunta e acrescentar isso

Comment: E até que ponto uma informação sem fontes confiáveis é uma informação válida? Palavras bonitas organizadas em uma sequência bem construída não torna a informação verdadeira.

Comment: Mas pelo menos vale a pena citar a informação, e mesmo podendo não ser verdade imagino que há grandes chances de ser verdade

Comment: Eu inventei essa história apenas para mostrar que uma conclusão que busca confirmar a premissa sempre parece verdade. O problema acontece quando a premissa não é válida, o que torna a conclusão equivocada. É um erro de metodologia em que busca-se confirmar as premissas e não os fatos.

Comment: ? Não entendi, mas eu já tinha pesquisado sobre o assunto e encontrei uma história do tipo

Comment: @NinjaTroll poste pra gente ver onde tinha algo assim. Você notou que acabou de confirmar o que o Woss disse e é por isso que suas perguntas andam mal recebidas? Você parte de uma premissa errada e aí quer que ela seja verdadeira de qualquer jeito. Essa salvou mas ficou claro que ela já tinha uma premissa falsa, talvez ela deveria ter sido fechadas, você não faz perguntas para aprender algo e sim para confirmarem o que você deseja, mesmo que seja um erro. Você vai complicando sua situação. Talvez por esse motivo a resposta tem negativo, ele foi dado baseado em premissa falsa.

Comment: Você parte da premissa que existe uma relação entre as strings na programação e linhas. Eu apenas inventei uma história que satisfaz a sua premissa e por isso aprece verdadeira, porque era a justificativa que você queria ler, sendo verdade ou não.  Uma versão melhorada da sua pergunta séria "por que strings são chamadas assim? Existe alguma relação com o significado da palavra em inglês?". Pode parecer bem semelhante à sua, mas muda o contexto da pergunta completamente.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/why-is-a-string-called-a-string/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401975/why-are-strings-called-strings, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880195/the-history-behind-the-definition-of-a-string

Comment: A pergunta é bastante interessante, no entanto devo ressaltar que apesar de correlacionada a programação não é de fato sobre isto, a pergunta me parece que caberia a comunidade https://english.stackexchange.com/, porque veja desta forma, o termo *string* não quer dizer LINHA, em uma tradução simples pode até levar a isto, mas imagine a frase *"a string of islands"* se refere a uma sequencia ou série de ilhas, outro exemplo *" a string of rigorous budgets"* (série de orçcamentos rigorosos), ou seja, não é nem sempre tão "ao pé da letra". São apenas exemplos.

Comment: Note que uma pergunta de 2009 existir no SOen não necessariamente significa o tipo de pergunta se encaixar no contexto, muitas vezes perguntas antigas são mantidas, mesmo que hoje não sendo mais aceitas, somente pq tiveram um grande numero de acessos e são antigas demais para migrar para outro site da rede (uma limitação do sistema)

Comment: Outras respostas relacionadas: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43329/etymology-of-string, https://www.quora.com/Why-are-strings-called-strings-in-programming

Comment: Nenhum desses links confirmam alguma coisa próxima da estória inventada pelo Woss.

Comment: Eu não disse que eles confirmavam, eu apenas disse que tinha visto algo do tipo

Comment: De acordo com Merriam-Webster uma string é uma serie de alguma coisa em linha. 

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/string

<a string of cars> ou <a string of names> 

Passamos a usar string para representar uma serie de caracteres em linha.

Answer (score 11):

A tradução ou mesmo expressão em inglês pode ter vários significados e eu não vi "linha" em todos que tive acesso. O mais comum é corda ou alguma variação disto. Uma tradução possível e que costuma ser emprestada para esse mecanismo da programação é uma cadeia de linhas, ou linhas entrelaçadas, que é a definição de corda. Em alguns contextos a linha pode não ser o foco e a cadeia de alguma coisa toma lugar. No caso é uma **cadeia de caracteres**, cadeia no sentido de várias coisas encadeadas (como em cadeia de montanhas), não de prisão.

Então *string* é uma sequência de caracteres, é uma forma de designar uma coleção de dados heterogêneos com um significado especial e muito usado em códigos. Então o valor que compõe um texto qualquer tem esse nome, e muitas vezes o tipo do objeto que tem essa informação é também chamada de `string` ou `String` em algumas linguagens.

Algumas linguagens possuem formatos específicos, mas a regra é ser uma cadeia de caracteres ou *character string* pra ser mais completo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Queria entender o motivo de alguém negativar esse tipo de resposta. ela responde sucintamente o que foi questionado

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza a maioria dos negativos que os moderadores recebem é por conta de vingança por pergunta fechada ou por moderação que contraria os sentimentos do moderado. Não estou afirmando ser esse o caso, mas se fizer a query para obter o usuário(coisa que desaconselho pois dá azia e gera conflito saber quem nos negativou) mas normalmente se levantar quem negativa perguntas e respostas do Maniero e o Bacco provavelmente vai encontrar um histórico de perguntas fechadas.

Comment: Sim, comentei mais para provocar o tipo de gente que faz isso, é fácil negativar e sumir depois sem dar explicação, ainda que a reposta fosse ruim, mas não há motivo para isso, negativo ao meu ver é para sinalizar conteúdo ruim

Comment: E como moderador eu não darei detalhes, mas nós sabemos quando isto acontece, e muitas vezes acaba passando para não parecer que o moderador que passa perseguir a pessoa. A incoerência desse negativo específico é quase inacreditável.